# C: Linked list word frequency - Standard input

Tags: c, linked-list, nodes, frequency

Edit: Fixed duplication error in code.
I attempted to create a word frequency analysis program that reads in from standard input.
I have two questions.

1. Currently I am using '\n' to indicate when my program should stop reading in input, I need it to read until the user is done typing. Would it be better to use EOF or the null terminator '\0'
2. This may be a dumb question but I cannot figure out what is wrong with my output it doubles the letters up every time.

Example input: "This is a test test of the program for frequency is a this for for"

Output:

```
thhiiss 1
iiss 2
aa 2
tteesstt 2
ooff 1
tthhee 1
pprrooggrraamm 1
ffoorr 3
ffrreeqquueennccyy 1
tthhiiss 1
```

As you can see the count close to correct for each word, but cannot figure out why the letters are duplicating.
Here is the code I have used:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "list.h"

#define MAXWORD 100

//===========================================================================
struct lnode {
    struct lnode *next;
    struct lnode *counter;
    struct lnode *pLast;   
    struct lnode *prev;
    struct lnode *head;
    char *word;
    int line;
    int count;
    int freq;
};

struct lnode *start = NULL;

//===========================================================================
struct lnode *createWordCounter(char *str)
  {
     struct lnode *pCounter = NULL;
     pCounter = (struct lnode*)malloc(sizeof(struct lnode));
     pCounter->word = (char*)malloc(strlen(str)+1);
     strcpy(pCounter->word, str);
     pCounter->freq = 1;
     pCounter->next = NULL;
     return pCounter;
  }
//===========================================================================
void addWord(char *str)
{
  struct lnode *pCounter = NULL;
  struct lnode *pLast = NULL;

  if(start == NULL)
  {
    start = createWordCounter(str);
    return;
  }
  // If the word is in the list, increment its count 
  pCounter = start;
  int temp = pCounter->freq;
  while(pCounter != NULL)
  {
    if(strcmp(str, pCounter->word) == 0)
    {
      pCounter->freq++;
      return;
    }
    pLast = pCounter;            
    pCounter = pCounter->next;  
  }

  // Word is not in the list, add it 
  pLast->next = createWordCounter(str);
}
//===========================================================================
int getNextWord(char *buf, int bufsize) {
    char *p = buf;
    char ch;
    do {
        ch = getchar();
        if (ch == '\n') 
            return 0;
        } while (!((ch >= 'A' && ch <= 'Z')||( ch >= 'a' && ch <= 'z')));
    do {
        if (p - buf < bufsize - 1){
             if( ch >= 97 && ch <= 122)//making the ch lowercase if needed
                   *p++ = ch;
             else{ch += 32;
                  *p++ = ch;}
              }//End of if
        ch = getchar();
        } while (((ch >= 'A' && ch <= 'Z')||( ch >= 'a' && ch <= 'z')));
        *p = '\0';
        return 1;
        }
//===========================================================================
void show(struct lnode *pWord)
{
printf("%s %i\n", pWord->word, pWord->freq);
}
//===========================================================================

int main(){
    struct lnode *counter = NULL;
    int size = 1000;
    char buf[MAXWORD];
    while(getNextWord(buf, size) != 0 ){
        addWord(buf);
    }

    counter = start;

    while(counter != NULL)
    {
        show(counter);
        counter = counter->next;
    }

    counter = start;

    while(counter != NULL)
    {
    free(counter->word);
    start = counter;
    counter = counter->next;
    free(start);
    }

return 0;
}
```

This is my first time posting so please let me know if I did anything wrong. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Is the word count really correct? Doesn't seem that way to me.

Comment: It is close, I edited my post, but I am trying to solve the first two problems first. Thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Would it be better to use EOF or the null terminator '\0' ?
```

Use EOF because if you press `ctl+D` `getchar()` consider input as `EOF` . You can also use `\n` or Use an OR logic with `\n`,`EOF`

```
what is wrong with my output it doubles the letters up every time ?
```

See this below code in  function  `getNextWord()`

```
   if( ch >= 97 && ch <= 122)//making the ch lowercase if needed
           *p++ = ch;   
      //this checks if input character is lowercase character, then store it into buffer
     else{ch += 32;} // if input character is lowercase character, won't execute else part
          *p++ = ch;   
          // now again you are copying same input character into buffer next location
```

Modify above part.

Comment: I did not know that thank you, I have edited my code to fix the duplication error. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Most welcome. yes your fix is correct. Check ctype functions [Here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/Main_Page) and [Here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/sscanf/) to make your program more readable.

Answer (score 1):

Look at this carefully, it is assigning `ch` twice to `*p`

```
     if( ch >= 97 && ch <= 122)//making the ch lowercase if needed
           *p++ = ch;
     else{ch += 32;}
       *p++ = ch;
```

I think the trailing "}" on the else statement is misplaced.

```
     if( ch >= 97 && ch <= 122) { //making the ch lowercase if needed
           *p++ = ch;
     } else {
       ch += 32;
       *p++ = ch;
     }
```

Also, your code will be greatly more readable if you learn about the functions
`isalpha`, `islower`, `isupper`, `tolower`, `toupper`. **man ctype** for info.

Comment: Thank you so much. Yeah i realized that after I posted, sorry I am new to coding I really appreciate your help! I realize that I could use those but this was for a lab that was due awhile ago and we were not allowed to use ctype.

Comment: @user2856537, click the checkmark by the down arrow if this answer is acceptable to you. Thanks. Good luck.